# Elegant way to optionally supply an argument to a function in R?

Tags: r, function, arguments

For the sake of example, let's say I have a function with several optional arguments:

```
result <- function_with_several_optional_arguments(a=1, b=2, c=3)
```

Depending on a variable `foo`, I want to either supply `d=1` or let it take its default value, which is unknown to me.

I could do

```
if (foo) {
    result <- function_with_several_optional_arguments(a=1, b=2, c=3, d=1)
} else {
    result <- function_with_several_optional_arguments(a=1, b=2, c=3)
}
```

but this quickly leads to a lot of code duplication - especially if I want to conditionally supply many arguments.

How can I conditionally supply an argument or leave it default?

Ideally I'd do something like

```
result <- function_with_several_optional_arguments(a=1, b=2, c=3, ifelse(foo, d=1))
```

but I don't know if there's any support for something like that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `do.call`:

```
Args <- list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)
if (foo) Args$d <- 1
do.call("fun", Args)
```

The second line could also be written: `Args$d <- if (foo) 1`